# Spring boot validation cannot resolve method 'groups'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation

I want to validate DTO's fields by groups, but something goes wrong.
Here's my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/in")
@RequestMapping("demoIn")
public ResponseEntity<String> demoIncome(@RequestBody @NotNull @Validated(DemoDto.InValidation.class) DemoDto demoDto)
```

And here's my DTO:

```
@Data
public class DemoDto {

public interface InValidation{}
public interface OutValidation{}

@NotNull(groups = {InValidation.class, OutValidation.class})
private String name;
...
```

The error is `Cannot resolve method 'groups'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your import is correct:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
```

I had an import of a class with the same name from another package